# parent.window.frames("framename").navigate(url); gives Function expected error in IE Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, frameset

Updating a legacy site in ASP that uses frames/framesets.  We can only use this site using IE or Edge which is fine, but we have to set emulation/compatibility mode to IE 5.

The issue I am getting:

```
 parent.window.frames("framename").navigate(url);
```

Kicks an error in the IE debugger when using anything other than IE5 mode:

```
Function expected
```

Is there a new way to accomplish the same thing?  Someone suggested using:

```
 parent.window.frames("framename").location.href(url);
```

But didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to set the source of an iframe? If so, try more like parent.window.frames["foo"].src = url;

Comment: um, not sure why you are using frames as a method. window.frames is an object, there should not be () used at all.

Comment: So you have users using windows 98???? With a browser that is like 23 years old

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I answer my own question faster than the crowd :)

This works with IE 9+

```
parent.window.frames["framename"].navigate(url);
```

But to coexist so my IE 5 emulated users can still use the site I had to wrap it in a condition:

```
if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode>8@*/')()) {
    parent.window.frames["framename"].navigate(url);
} else {
    parent.window.frames("framename").navigate(url);
}
```

This checks the browser/emulation level and uses the appropriate syntax.  This is working for me.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.